# copying and building the downloaded project in vs201o

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I have downloaded few projects based on c# & asp.net from internet as well as I have few projects in CD. Recently I installed microsoft visual studo 2010 ultimate setup on my pc having window 7.Now, I want to know how to copy the downloaded or CD project(c# , asp.net) to visual studio and run that. I'm new to programming field, so just want to view some sample projects.
Please tell me step-by-step procedure how to copy and build the projects in vs2010 ultimate.

Comment: Better to google it.....

Answer (score 0):

1 Open Visual Studio

2 Access to File

3 Create New Solution

4 Access to Solution Explorer ( Shortcut CTRL + ALT + L)

5 Right click on solution and select Add existing project

6 Browse to your project (Extension .csprog) and click on